# Convert utf8 into html entities in Perl

Tags: perl

I've inherited a horrible site, so please forgive this question :) Rather than upgrading the site into fully UTF8, we need to convert any non-standard chars into HTML entities:

```
&#ord_value;
```

This test script does this for one charachter:

```
$foo =~ s/(\x{ed})/to_ord($1)/e;

sub to_ord {
    return ("&#" . ord($_[0]). ";")
}
```

What I need to do though, is trigger this on anything greater than ord 127. Is there an easy way I can do this? I've looked into the character classes but can't see anything that fits the bill

**FWIW**, I've made them aware that the way they currently store the data is horrible, and will cause issues with people trying to search on the HTML entities - but this is out of my control.

**UPDATE:** This works, but I'm sure there must be a better way to do it - so please do share if you have a suggestion :)

```
s/([^a-z \.,-_0-9])/to_ord($1)/eg
```

Comment: You want https://metacpan.org/pod/HTML::Entities.

Comment: @simbabque thanks, I did try that, but wasn't too keen on bloating it out even more just for that one feature :) (when it can be done with a regex)

Comment: You can <strike>steal</strike> borrow the essential regex. Your code is fine though.

Comment: @AndrewNewby Don't reinvent the wheel. `HTML::Entities` is an old module, meaning it has taken care of bugs you don't even know exist. Bloat is not a problem on modern computers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
s/(...)/ ... /eg;
```

Choices of patterns:

- `[^\x00-\x21\x23-\x25\x28-\x3B\x3D\x3F-\x7F]` (Escape non-ASCII.)
- `[^\x09\x0A\x0D\x20-\x21\x23-\x25\x28-\x3B\x3D\x3F-\x7E]` (Escape non-ASCII and control characters.)

Choices of replacement expressions:

- `"&#".ord($1).";"`
- `sprintf("&#x%X;", ord($1))` (Extra CPU, but reduced bandwidth.)

For example,

```
s/([^\x09\x0A\x0D\x20-\x21\x23-\x25\x28-\x3B\x3D\x3F-\x7E])/ sprintf("&#x%X;", ord($1)) /eg;
```

Comment: Forgot to exclude `<`, `>`, `&`, `'` and `"`" from the exclusion list so they would get escaped. Fixed.